# Complex Query strategy

Tags: mysql

I'm developing a database and I need to create a query. The database will save the information from general alert having a main table "alert" that relate all the other tables information with that alert in the following way:

- The alert table contains the following columns: analyzer_id, create_time_id (...) and classification_id. 
  ( 1 to n relation between the alert and the rest of the tables)
- The alert_has_source table contains the the following columns: alert_id and source_id. 
  ( n to m relation between the alert and the source)
- The alert_has_targets contains the the following columns: alert_id and target_id. 
  ( n to m relation between the alert and the target)

[image]

I'm amateur at mysql so i'm not sure if the database is well designed and this is the way to express the information.

I need to query some columns form the table analyzer, classification, create_time, source (with node and address), target(with node and address) that need to be filter by the the table classification.ident = "log".

1) Should I create a view in the database and provide it with the query? Does that perform well?

2) Regarding the query should I use multiple selects or the inner join?

3) How to optimize the search due to the fact that I only need some part of the database?

Comment: 1) You could. No. 2) Generally, INNER JOIN will outperform multiple selects. 3) Indexes are key (excuse the pun)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not as specific as it could be about the result set you require. That makes it difficult to answer specifically.

Nevertheless, here is an attempt.

> 1) Should I create a view in the database and provide it with the query?

You can do that. It's a convenient way to encapsulate a complex query. Get the query working first, then make a view from it.

> Does that perform well?

In MySQL views typically have very similar performance to their single-query equivalents. Other databases (PostgreSQL, Oracle for example) have optimizations for views.

> 2) Regarding the query should I use multiple selects or the inner join?

If you need a certain result set -- a certain virtual table with one row per interesting item -- that's composed from your tables, you should use a strategy of JOINing the tables. If you need a bunch of loosely related data points from different tables, you can SELECT those data points separately.

INNER JOIN is a type of JOIN. Sometimes you may need LEFT JOINs instead. `a LEFT JOIN b` may serve you better when table `a` contains rows missing from table `b`.   INNER JOIN suppresses rows from the result set unless they appear on both sides of the join.

> 3) How to optimize the search due to the fact that 
>   I only need some part of the database?

That's the purpose of indexes in SQL. You can read about it here.  http://use-the-index-luke.com/

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I will start to create the query and for the optimization I will index the components for the "where" clause.

Comment: Be careful with the indexing. It's hard for MySQL to take advantage of multiple indexes in a table. A well-chosen compound index works much better.